# jQuery check if height of CSS class is less than 20%

Tags: jquery, css

Okay so I have a question.

I simply want to make it so if a CSS class #hunger .bg is less than 20% height so height: 20%;
Then it needs to execute a jQuery code.

I have this now but this doesn't seem to work!

```
if ($('#hunger .bg').css('height') < '20%') {
    alert('Less than 20% hunger');
}
```

Comment: I think your problem here is that `'20%'` is a string, not a number. You need to extract the numeric part of the height property, parse it to an integer and then compare it to another integer. You can't do maths on strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that .css('height') is returning a value like "20px" which you can't perform mathematical operations on. Simply use .height() and find the percentage with simple math.

```js
let height = $('#hunger .bg').height() / $('#hunger').height() * 100;

if(height < 20){
  alert("Less than 20% hunger");
}
```

```css
#hunger {
  height:100px;
}

div {
  background-color:lightgray;
  height:19%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hunger">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```